# How do I use list comprehension with an if-else statement to print if the action has been completed or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

So I have a code which asks to find the name of the driver and if it exists to delete that list from the main driver details list. I used a nested list to achieve this. And after deleting the list, I want a message to be displayed saying "Record Deleted" or else "Record Not found".

```
driver_details=[["Ken Block","55","Hoonigan","Mustang"], ["Ken Miles","48","Ford","Ford GT"]]

def delete_driver():
    """This function is used to delete driver details
    by entering the driver name"""
    global driver_details
    driver_name=input("Enter driver name: ")
    if driver_name in driver_details:
        driver_details=[x for x in driver_details if x[0] not in driver_name]
        print("Driver details deleted")
    else:
        print("Record Not Found")
    print(driver_details)
    options()
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.

However when I try this:

```
    """This function is used to delete driver details
    by entering the driver name"""
    global driver_details
    driver_name=input("Enter driver name: ")
    driver_details=[x for x in driver_details if x[0] not in driver_name ]
    print("Driver details deleted")
    print(driver_details)
    options()
```

It does delete the record.

I expected the answer to print as Record Deleted yet I keep getting Record not found even though the name of the driver does exist. How could I add an if statement to this?

Comment: Please post the shortest full program which demonstrates the problem. The code you have posted so far is obviously broken, because the `drivers_list` variable is not defined, and `else ]` is a *SyntaxError* in Python.

Comment: The problem is most probably in the part of the code which you haven't posted yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me. However, there are 2 corrections:

1.You have to flatten the nested dictionary  `driver_details` to check `in` property

2. There is a typo `driver_name in drivers_details` should be `driver_name in driver_details`.

`driver_details=[["Ken Block","55","Hoonigan","Mustang"], ["Ken Miles","48","Ford","Ford GT"]]`

```
def delete_driver():
    """This function is used to delete driver details
    by entering the driver name"""
    global driver_details
    driver_name=input("Enter driver name: ")
    if driver_name in [item for sublist in driver_details for item in sublist]:  #flattened nested list
        driver_details=[x for x in driver_details if x[0] not in driver_name]
        print("Driver details deleted")
    else:
        print("Record Not Found")
    print(driver_details)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to delete from `driver_details`:

```
driver_details2 = [dd for dd in driver_details if dd[0] != driver_name]
driver_details[:] = driver_details2  # Overwrite original list.
```

There are some other problems with your code (as it is posted), for example the `drivers_list` variable is not defined. You can define it like this:

```
drivers_list = [dd[0] for dd in driver_details]
```

Answer (score -1):

def delete_driver():
"""This function is used to delete driver details
by entering the driver name"""
global driver_details
driver_name=input("Enter driver name: ")
if driver_name in [item for sublist in driver_details for item in sublist]:  #flattened nested list
driver_details=[x for x in driver_details if x[0] not in driver_name]
print("Driver details deleted")
else:
print("Record Not Found")
print(driver_details)
Followdef delete_driver():
"""This function is used to delete driver details
by entering the driver name"""
global driver_details
driver_name=input("Enter driver name: ")
if driver_name in [item for sublist in driver_details for item in sublist]:  #flattened nested list
driver_details=[x for x in driver_details if x[0] not in driver_name]
print("Driver details deleted")
else:
print("Record Not Found")
print(driver_details)

Comment: Hello ABHINAY, please try to format your code so it can be easily read and copy-pasted. especially because Python cares about whitespaces (spaces/tabs, linebreaks, etc...)